# Netlogo GIS: How can I create agents random location inside the specific region?

Tags: gis, netlogo

I have loaded shapfile and then I want to create turtles inside the map for simulating.
However, I use "gis:create-turtles-inside-polygon" then the agents just appear in same point. How can I put them in random places but inside the map?

with the following code

```
to setup-maps
  gis:load-coordinate-system "dem.prj"
  set Bangladesh gis:load-dataset "dem.shp"
  set elevation gis:load-dataset "dem.asc"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of elevation
  gis:set-drawing-color red + 2
  gis:draw Bangladesh 1
end


to setup-turtles
  foreach gis:feature-list-of Bangladesh [ this-vector-feature ->
    gis:create-turtles-inside-polygon this-vector-feature turtles 10 [
      set shape "person"
      set size 2.5
      set color white
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: As far as I see, `gis:create-turtles-inside-polygon` should automatically do it: I took the same steps as yours using some gis data found on the internet and turtles appear in random locations within the polygon. This makes me think that the problem lies somewhere in your data. If you do the same thing but using [this data](https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/4a0f12a6-0d12-4de4-a672-c387f39849bb) (the one I used), do you confirm that turtles appear in random locations inside the polygon?

Answer (score 0):

Are your shapefiles color coordinated? In which case you could make use of their color to determine where the turtles are placed.

A quick example of how I do this below.  I save my map as an image first (PNG), and then use the import-pcolors function in NetLogo. That skips the need for the GIS extension.

to define-airplane-regions
ask patches with [pcolor = 14.9] [set namibia true] ask patches with [pcolor = 45.3] [set botswana true] end

to appear-aircrafts
if any? patches with [namibia = true][ ask one-of patches with [namibia = true] [sprout-aircrafts 3]] end

I have a tutorial on YouTube showing how to do this in more detail. All code in the video description.

https://youtu.be/VzvgBzO7ls0